# to return value in function php from XML files

Tags: php, xml

I need help doing this. i cant figure out how to return the boolean, and it seems that my condition's not working.

this is my xml file called Details.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<OutofOffice>
<Employee>
    <EmployeeNewIC>590810125431</EmployeeNewIC>
    <EmployeeName>AWANG BAKAR BIN AWANG HUSSIN  </EmployeeName>
    <position> Admin Officer   </position>
    <Gred>NA48</Gred>
    <DateBegin>24/05/2016 08:00:00</DateBegin>
    <DateEnd>27/05/2016 17:00:00</DateEnd>
    <Ind>outstation</Ind>
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <EmployeeNewIC>591006125419</EmployeeNewIC>
    <EmployeeName>BRUNO VUN   </EmployeeName>
    <position>officer    </position>
    <Gred>VU07</Gred>
    <DateBegin>05/05/2016</DateBegin>
    <DateEnd>28/05/2016</DateEnd>
    <Ind>outstations</Ind>
</Employee>
<Employee>
    <EmployeeNewIC>610810125695</EmployeeNewIC>
    <EmployeeName>DAVID BIN GABRIEL            </EmployeeName>
    <position>driver       </JawatanHakiki>
    <Gred>HA11</Gred>
    <DateBegin>23/05/2016 08:00:00</DateBegin>
    <DateEnd>27/05/2016 17:30:00</DateEnd>
    <Ind>sick leaves</Ind>
</Employee>
</OutofOffice>
```

below is my php code

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("Details.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");


function SearchSu($Su1 , $Su2)
{
    //boolean 
    $av1 = false; //false => the supervisor is not in the list (AVAILABLE)
    $av2 = false;

    //set the  officer
    $Su1 = "591006125411"; //Bruno
    $Su2 = "571121125351"; //Dayana

    foreach($xml->Employee as $Employee) //problem occur here though
    {
        if($Su1 == $Employee->EmployeeNewIC) // true=>supervisor is out
        {
            //if supervisor1 is out, procees check with supervisor2
            if($Su2 == $Employee->EmployeeNewIC ) 
            {   
                return $av1 = false; //true=>supervisor is out 

            }
            else if($Su2 !== $Employee->EmployeeNewIC) // false=>supervisor is available
            { 
                return $av2;    
            }
        }
        else
            return $av1;

    }
SearchSu("591006125411","571121125351");

?>
```

i would very much appreciate the help.

Comment: What is `$xml_array` ?

Comment: i just edit it. can you check it back? @ArshidKV